# Convert a column of json strings into columns of data

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a big dataframe of around 30000 rows and a single column containing a json string. Each json string contains a number of variables and its value I want to break this json string down into columns of data

two rows looks like

```
0 {"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3"}
1 {"a" ;"4","b":"5","c":"6"}
```

I want to convert this into a dataframe like

```
a   b   c
1   2   3
4   5   6
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Your column values seem to have an extra number before the actual json string. So you might want strip that out first (skip to **Method** if that isn't the case)

One way to do that is to apply a function to the column

```
# constructing the df
df = pd.DataFrame([['0 {"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3"}'],['1 {"a" :"4","b":"5","c":"6"}']], columns=['json'])

# print(df)
                         json
# 0  0 {"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3"}
# 1  1 {"a" :"4","b":"5","c":"6"}

# function to remove the number
import re

def split_num(val):
    p = re.compile("({.*)")
    return p.search(val).group(1)

# applying the function
df['json'] = df['json'].map(lambda x: split_num(x))
print(df)

#                          json
# 0   {"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3"}
# 1  {"a" :"4","b":"5","c":"6"}
```

---

**Method:**

Once the `df` is in the above format, the below will convert each row entry to a dictionary:

```
df['json'] = df['json'].map(lambda x: dict(eval(x)))
```

Then, applying `pd.Series` to the column will do the job

```
d = df['json'].apply(pd.Series)
print(d)
#   a  b  c
# 0  1  2  3
# 1  4  5  6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(json_file) as f:
    df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(line) for line in f)
```