# Creating a dataframe from values extracted from a json column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I loaded a .csv file into a df, and one of the row of a columns contains a list of dictionary like below.

```
data = [{"character": "Jake Sully", "gender": 2,}, {"character": "Neytiri", "gender": 1},                                                         
        {"character": "Dr. Grace Augustine","gender": 1},         
        {"character": "Col. Quaritch", "gender": 2]
```

But of course after loading it, it's read as a string. So, I converted each row in the column to a json, which makes it easy to extract values based on the key name. I then need to create a seperate df like so.

```
df = {'character': ['Jake Sully','Neytiri', 'Dr. Grace Augustine', 'Col.Quaritch'], 
    'gender': [2, 1, 1, 2]}
```

This is my code but I can't quite get the desired df ouput right.

```
df = pd.DataFrame() #create new df
keys = ['character','gender'] #keys to extract values from json
lst=[]
for val in data: #to iterate over data series
    for object in json.loads(val):
        for key in keys:
            lst.append(object[key])
    df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(lst,columns=[key])], axis=1)
```

Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: [Related?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50656469/convert-a-column-of-json-strings-into-columns-of-data/50658993#50658993)

Answer (score 2):

`pd.DataFrame` accepts a list of dictionaries directly:

```
data = [{"character": "Jake Sully", "gender": 2,},
        {"character": "Neytiri", "gender": 1},
        {"character": "Dr. Grace Augustine","gender": 1},
        {"character": "Col. Quaritch", "gender": 2}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)  # or pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

print(df)

             character  gender
0           Jake Sully       2
1              Neytiri       1
2  Dr. Grace Augustine       1
3        Col. Quaritch       2
```

Therefore, you only need to extract a list of dictionaries from your json file. One way you can do this is via `json.loads`.

A better idea is to read your data directly into a dataframe via `pd.read_json`.

Comment: Thanks, but as I have mentioned, the file is a .csv file, which contains one column that is a list of dictionary. And after pd.read_csv('filename.csv'), I did use json.loads in the code above.

Comment: I did, but i get a ValueError: Expected object or value. That's why i loaded as pd.read_csv('filename.csv'), after which i iterate over each row in the column and then use json.loads(row_in_col_on_interst).

Comment: Sorry! typo. V is actually the iterator val in for val in data: have updated it.

Comment: @Zoozoo, You can try including `pd.read_csv('filename.csv').to_dict()` in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I may be don't understand your question completely, but I am able to get df just fine.

```
data = [{"character": "Jake Sully", "gender": 2,}, 
         {"character": "Neytiri", "gender": 1},
         {"character": "Dr. Grace Augustine","gender": 1},
         {"character": "Col. Quaritch", "gender": 2}]

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Out:

```
             character       gender
0           Jake Sully       2
1              Neytiri       1
2  Dr. Grace Augustine       1`
```

Comment: data represents only ONE row of the column of interest. It's to show that after i loaded the .csv file using pd.read_csv('filename.csv'), this column is loaded as string.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out.

```
df = pd.DataFrame() #create new df
keys = ['character','gender'] #keys to extract values from json
for i,key in enumerate(keys):
     lst_i = []
     for row in data: #iterating over the rows in the cols of interest 
          for object in json.loads(row):
              lst_i.append(object[key])
     df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(lst_i,columns=[key])], axis=1)
```